# Can xdebug profile selected directories?

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

I am trying to set up xdebug for profiling and it seems all the files xdebug detects are under /var/lib64. I need to have files under /var/www/ to be profiled. Is there any parameter to configure this? Can we select multiple directories for code that needs to be profiled?

I am using webgrind to look at this output, and xdebug isn't able to provide with the right files :(